# Python: Add date and time to a radio webstream recording

Tags: python, datetime

Been searching for solutions for a whole day, but none of them were of any help. 
Anyway, what i have been trying to do is to add a date and time into the filename to a radio web stream recording. But i keep getting an error message :

> File "streamrunskyplus.py", line 9, in  filename =
>   'home/somebody/streams/streamrunskyplus.py'%datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

And here is the code itself

```
import subprocess
import os
import datetime

os.system("command")
 subprocess.call(['streamripper', 'http://stream05.akaver.com/skyplus_low.ogg', '-d', './streams', '-l', '20', '-a', 'Skyplus', ])

 filename = 'home/somebody/streams/streamrunskyplus.py'%datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filename = 'home/somebody/streams/streamrunskyplus.py'%datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%Y%m%d-%H%M%S")
```

You'll have to put an %s in your first string. 'home/somebody/streams/streamrunskyplus.py'

Put %s on the place where you want to put the date.

Example: If you want to put it on the end:

'home/somebody/streams/streamrunskyplus.py%s'

Would do the trick